# Error when running cmd line invoke Python

Tags: python

I'm working on a script to scan a network for active users using the NMAP cmd line invoke: My code is below:

```
import socket, subprocess, nmap, time,os, invoke


ipaddr = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
print (ipaddr)

ip = ipaddr
proc = subprocess.Popen('ipconfig',stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
while True:
    line = proc.stdout.readline()
    if ip.encode() in line:
        break
mask = proc.stdout.readline().rstrip().split(b':')[-1].replace(b'     ',b'').decode()
print(mask)
network = ip + "/" + mask
print(network)
t0 = time.clock()

print("Using network: " + network)
cmd = 'nmap -n -sP -T4 ' + network + ' 2>&1'
res = invoke(cmd)
lines = res.split('\n')
print(lines)
for i in lines:
    m = find('Host\s+\(?([0-9\.]+)\)?\s+appears to be up.', i)
    if m:
        print(m, "\t", nslookup(m))

t1 = time.clock()
print("Scan complete!")
print("it took %d seconds to scan", (t1-t0))
```

I'm getting the following error:

line 21, in 
    res = invoke(cmd)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Please help :D

Comment: What is not clear about the error? You are calling a module which makes no sense. You probably want to call a _specific_ function in this module like `invoke.some_function(cmd)`...

Comment: Now I'm getting a file path error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are invoking the module not a function inside this module. You should use the run function to run a shell command. So at the top of the file use a local import of `run` and change your line 21 to `run(cmd)`:

```
from invoke import run

run(cmd)
```

On the other hand, if you want to use `import invoke`, you will have to change line 21 to:

```
invoke.run(cmd)
```